# ASP MVC 3 create Partial View or Custom Helper with params

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am very new to asp.mvc 3. I am using kendoui and knockout for binding. My application looks like this sample:

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> MyOptions1 { get; set; }
        public string MyChoice1 { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<string> MyOptions2 { get; set; }
        public string MyChoice2 { get; set; }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            MyOptions1 = new List<string>()
                             {
                                 "OptionA",
                                 "OptionB"
                             };

            MyOptions2 = new List<string>()
                             {
                                 "OptionC",
                                 "OptionD"
                             };
        }
    }
```

Index method of Home controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Index View:

```
<div id="optionsArea">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Option1:</label></td>
            <td><input id="options1" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: MyOptions1, value: MyChoice1 }" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Option2:</label></td>
            <td><input id="options2" data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: MyOptions2, value: MyChoice2 }" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When Index view is loaded I am calling `OptionsData` method of controller which returns the populated `MyViewModel` as Json.

```
public ActionResult OptionsData()
        {
            var myModel = new MyViewModel();
            var jsonNetResult = new JsonNetResult
            {
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
                Data = myModel
            };

            return jsonNetResult;
        }
```

In javascript From `MyViewModel` I create populated javascript viewmodel `viewModel` with knockout observable properties and bind it to the div in the Index View.

```
$(function () {

    my = {

    }

    $.getJSON("/Home/OptionsData", function (data) {

        // create observable properties from MyViewModel
        my.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

        ko.applyBindings(my.viewModel, document.getElementById("optionsArea"));
    });
});
```

In my application I have many elements containing label and dropdown so I want to extract that part in something like a component and reuse it calling it with some parameters to replace the bindings. I read some articles and maybe the solution is to use partial views or custom HTML helpers so I can do something like this:

_OptionPartialView

```
<tr>
    <td><label>Option2:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: (parameter1), value: (parameter2) }" /></td>
</tr>
```

where somehow I want to replace parameter1 and parameter 2 when I call the partial in the Index View:

```
@Html.Partial("_OptionPartialView.cshtml", parameter1, parameter2);
```

or with helper method:

```
@Html.MyCustomHelper(..., parameter1, parameter2);
```

Then I will strongly bind my Index method to the Index view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var myModel = new MyViewModel();
            return View(myModel);
        }
```

And my view will look something like this:

```
  @model MVC3Question.Models.MyViewModel

<div id="optionsArea">
    <table>
        @Html.Partial("_OptionPartialView.cshtml", Model.MyOptions1, Model.MyChoice1);
        @Html.Partial("_OptionPartialView.cshtml", Model.MyOptions2, Model.MyChoice2);
    </table>
</div>
```

My question is which is better in this situation Partial View or Custom Helper method and more important how do I implement them with the parameters having in mind the posted sample code. Any other approches or ideas are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion both methods are good. 
You can create a custom helper that takes two parameters like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyHtmlHelper(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string label, IEnumerable<string> option, string choise)
    {
        var html = new MvcHtmlString(String.Empty);

            html = MvcHtmlString.Create("<tr><td><label>" + label + ":</label></td><td><input data-bind=\"kendoDropDownList: { data: (" + option + "), value: (" + choise + ") }\" /></td></tr>");


        return html;
    }
```

I would prefer this method because it will work without any change in your current code.

If you want to use a partial view you will need to change your current model.

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        MyOptions = new List<string();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> MyOptions { get; set; }
    public string MyChoice { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can populate the model in your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModels = new List<MyViewModel>();
        var myOptions1 = new List<string>()
                         {
                             "OptionA",
                             "OptionB"
                         };

        var myOptions2 = new List<string>()
                         {
                             "OptionC",
                             "OptionD"
                         };
        viewModels.Add(new MyViewModel{MyOptions = myOptions1});
        viewModels.Add(new MyViewModel{MyOptions = myOptions2});
        return View(viewModels);
    }
```

After that you need to change your view like this:

```
    @model IList<MVC3Question.Models.MyViewModel>
<div id="optionsArea">
    <table>
        @foreach(var viewModel in Model)
        {
            @Html.Partial("_OptionPartialView.cshtml", viewModel);
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

And finally create a partial view:

```
    @model Mvc3Question.Models.MyViewModel
<tr>
    <td><label>Option2:</label></td>
    <td><input data-bind="kendoDropDownList: { data: (@Model.MyOptions), value: (@Model.MyChoice) }" /></td>
</tr>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. For the second approach with the partial view, in my real application the MyViewModel object contains a lot of data and logic and it is not an option to return a list of view models strongly typed to the view. Maybe, create separate mini viewmodel for every component and bind it to the partial view (as the viewmodel from your example).Also is there an option to extract the html code from the html helper method in another file and take it from there or something like this. I do not like very much the idea of messing the template code with the c# code.

Comment: I don't know of a way to extract the html from the html helper. Actually it is not recommended to use such helpers, because they are an anti pattern and hard to customize afterwords.
For the model you can create another model that contains MyOptions and MyChoise and use it as List<MyMiniViewModel> in the bigger model.